# object not found (error 404) after clicking submit codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Everytime I click the login submit button it goes to "Object not Found" error 404! I've been looking at my codes for hours and couldn't find the right solution. Please help! thanks!

login_controller.php

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Login_controller extends CI_Controller {

        public function index(){
            $this->load->view('template/header');
            $this->load->view('login_view');
                echo "<script> alert('x'); </script>";
        }

        public function login(){
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');

            $successful = $this->login_model->login($email,$password);

            if($successful){
                $this->home();
            } else {
                echo "<script> alert('x'); </script>";
            }
        }

        function home(){
            if($this->session->userdata('email') != ""){
                // $this->load->view('template/header');
                // $this->load->view('home_view');
                echo "<script> alert('y'); </script>";      
            } else {
                // $this->load->view('template/header');
                // $this->load->view('login_view');
                echo "<script> alert('n'); </script>";
            }
        }
    }   
?>
```

login_view.php

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>

<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>public/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>public/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">


    <form class="form-login" method="post" action="login_controller/login">

        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>public/img/q_logo.png">

        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log in</button>

    </form>

</div>
```

login_model.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login_model extends CI_Model {

    function login($email,$password){
        $this->db->where("email",$email);
        $this->db->where("password",$password);

        $query=$this->db->get("users");

        if($query->num_rows()>0){
            foreach($query->result() as $rows){
                $newdata = array(
                    'email'     =>$rows->email,
                    'firstname' =>$rows->firstname,
                    'lastname'  =>$rows->lastname
                );
            }
            $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Make your file name for controller Login_controller.php and not login_controller.php

Comment: One question, it logs a stacktrace log or simply 404? You're code looks fine, maybe it is your webserver or CI config.

Answer (score 2):

Go application > config > config.php

Make sure that your base url is correctly entered, with `/` at the end

example:
`$config['base_url'] = 'http://192.168.7.123/admin/';`

Note the `/` at the end.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks right. Your view exists? You entered the right name? I guess this your problem.

And open your form tag using form_open().

Comment: i think the problem is that, everytime i click the button it displays that error, i'm using xampp.. its been days now and i still can't get it to fix